# Silence or ignore H18 errors in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, newrelic

On Heroku, I am getting a lot of H18 errors (request interrupted) due to the client closing the request. That's OK. However, they are being over-logged and I'd like them to be ignored. They are affecting my monitoring in Heroku and New Relic.

How can I silence or ignore H18 errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Heroku's logging is entirely outside of New Relic control. The agent wouldn't specifically see H18 errors as such.

Comment: We need to find a way to "unregister" H18 sock=client responses from the dashboard.